# Grafana using virtual machine (Ubuntu-Azure)

Tags: azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, grafana

How can I access Grafana using Ubuntu-Azure VM? I have sudo user privilege. I'm trying to access Grafana using Ubuntu so that my team can work on the same dashboard from different locations. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Ubuntu VM is a Linux OS without desktop so that you cannot access Grafana as you do in your local machine via the web browser. You need to install the desktop for the Ubuntu VM. Then you can access Grafana via the web browser. Here are the steps that [Install a desktop environment on your Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop).

But it's not a good idea to use the desktop in Ubuntu VM, it will waste a lot of resources. Windows Os is better at desktop than Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Charles! Thanks for responding. My problem is solved, I think the issues was that the port was blocked and since I only had sudo user privilege, I couldn't access it. It's unblocked now and I'm able to access it using the servers IP address. But now I have the same issues with MySQL, although I have changed the bind address to 0.0.0.0, I'm still unable to configure mysql to grafana.

Comment: @Akshi Where does the MySQL host? In the same VM?